# Combining CASE and LISTAGG in a REDSHIFT stateement

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Below is a snip of code in which I am trying to list all the product dates per product id. To avoid the LISTAGG size restriction, I', trying to only list dates within the last 12 months.

```
SELECT distinct product_id, as_of_date, 
CASE WHEN date_cmp(to_date(cast(as_of_date as text),'YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date(cast(add_months(current_date,-12) as TEXT),'YYYY-MM-DD')) > 0     
  THEN LISTAGG(as_of_date, ',')    
  WITHIN GROUP (Order by product.as_of_date)
  OVER (PARTITION BY product_id)
END  from product
```

On running this I get the error message

> "Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit"

which presumably means that the CASE isn't selecting only the last 12 months.

All the date casting was because without it I was getting date timestamp errors.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tested how many dates there are grouped by podukt and where last 12 month?

Comment: Yes. There are at most 12 dates which I am concatenating with an amount and they are both cast to text. So that could  be max 10 characters per date or 120 overall.

Answer (score 1):

You state you are "trying to only list dates within the last 12 months" but the case expression says "if the `as_of_date` is at most one year old, please return *all* dates of `product_id` partition".

I guess you rather want something like `listagg(case when date_cmp(...) then as_of_date else '' end, ',') within ...` or `listagg(distinct ...)` thereof.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still don't understand how I am picking up all dates! I do a CASE (when the current date minus one year is less than (I had the inequality wrong) the as_of_date THEN LISTAGG the date otherwise do nothing. I do exactly want your first version  - listagg(case when date_cmp(...) then as_of_date else '' end, ',') within ...

Comment: Because the data for listagg is taken from `partition by product_id`. Suppose there exists a million rows with product_id=1, of which only 10 rows being not older than year. Then in your query the database attempts to compute listagg for 10 rows but the base of aggregation is million rows. In Postgres the `filter (where ...)` clause could also be utilized in this case but I don't know whether Redshift supports it.